# How to enable reactjs styles in content security policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mantine, content-security-policy

I need to place the 'style-src 'self' security directive in my application's csp.

But this directive blocks styles defined by the external Mantine-UI style library. I can't use 'unsafe-inline' to enable styles, because it goes against security.

I create the settings in vite.config and assign the csp settings in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <%- csp %>
    
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you remove the 'style-src 'self' directive in vite.config you will see that styles will be enabled:

```
createHtmlPlugin({
          minify: true,
          inject: {
            data: {
              csp: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' blob: data: ; 
              style-src 'self';
              object-src 'none';
              upgrade-insecure-requests;
              block-all-mixed-content;
              form-action 'self';
              script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
              worker-src 'self' blob:;">`,
              viteDev: `<script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/@vite/client"></script>`,
            },
          },
        }),
```

One of the easiest ways to allow style tags when using CSP is to use a nonce, example:

```
<script nonce="rAnd0m">
    doWhatever();
</script>
```

The Mantine-UI style library that I use has the getStyleNonce function, which creates a nonce for each style tag dynamically. You can use devtools to inspect the html:

```
import { SHA256 } from "crypto-js";

function generateRandomHash() {
  const randomString =
    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  return SHA256(randomString).toString();
}

<MantineProvider getStyleNonce={generateRandomHash}>
...
```

Even using the nonce, I was unable to enable my styles. Can you help me find a way to enable them?

**Codesandbox:**  https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/staging-dew-jwcfw4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A26%2C5-26%2C57